# OnSelect Datepicker in Materialize to set Max Date + 9 between two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, materialize

I have two inputs between from date and to date, I want to set maxDate is 9 days reference first input. I use Materialize the latest version.

Example: when I select **1 August 2018** maxDate in `id="to"` is **10 August 2018**

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="from" value="from">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="to" value="to">
```

and my JS

```
$('#from').datepicker({
  autoClose : true,
  onSelect: function() {
    var minDate = $(this).setDate(new Date() + 9);
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate)
   }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
  autoClose : true,
  onSelect: function() {
    var maxDate = $(this).setDate(new Date() - 9);
    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate)
  }
})
```

I create `onSelect` like that is not working. I using Materialize, but stack here. Anybody help? thank you..
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/rt9780xs/58/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `onSelect()` to this :

```
onSelect: function() {

       var toYear = this.date.getFullYear();
       var toMonth = this.date.getMonth();
       var toDay = this.date.getDate();
       maxDate = new Date(toYear, toMonth, toDay + 9);

       $("#to").datepicker({
          format : 'dd mmm yyyy',
          defaultDate: maxDate,
          setDefaultDate:maxDate
       })
}
```

here is the solution : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt9780xs/104/)

Comment: Hi @bahman, I mean second input is refer by first input, for example if I select "1 August 2018" then maxDate in second input is "10 August 2018".